# Printar o nome de um dicionário em Python

Tags: python-3.x

Segue o código:

```
layla = {'tipo':'cachorro', 'nome_dono':'lucas'}
ratata = {'tipo':'rato', 'nome_dono': 'Dante'}
pikachu = {'tipo': 'furão', 'nome_dono':'Ash'}

pets = [layla, ratata, pikachu]
for animal in pets:
    print ("Nome do dono:", animal["nome_dono"].title(),"\nEspécie do animal:", animal["tipo"].title(), "\n")
```

Eu preciso também printar o nome do animal, que por sua vez é o nome do dicionário.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Precisa ter uma chave pro nome do animal, não?

Answer (score 1):

Para que você possa escrever na tela o valor do nome do animal, você deve criar uma chave com o nome de cada um, então só basta adicionar o mesmo objeto a essa chave. Há várias formas de fazer. Achei essa mais prática, porque deu para manter o seus 3 dicionários com o mesmo valor.

```
layla = {'tipo':'cachorro', 'nome_dono':'lucas'}
ratata = {'tipo':'rato', 'nome_dono': 'Dante'}
pikachu = {'tipo': 'furão', 'nome_dono':'Ash'}

pets = [{"layla":layla}, {"ratata": ratata}, {"pikachu":pikachu}]
for animal in pets:
  nome_animal = ""
  for e in animal:
    nome_animal = e
  print("Nome do animal: "+nome_animal)
  p = animal[nome_animal]
  print ("Nome do dono:", p["nome_dono"].title(),"\nEspécie do animal:", p["tipo"].title(), "\n")
```